# JavaScript tab control that works on SP 2010

Tags: 2010, javascript, css

I'm trying to use jQuery UI Tabs but it seems to conflict with SP2010 styles, do you know any alternative that Works with SP2010? Or maybe a way to fix this?

[image: Screenshot]

The same issue occurs with Bootstrap Twitter. Here is a code sample:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain the issue you are having further? I have one customized page in a site collection that uses jQuery tabs without any issues.

Comment: We're on 2010 and use jQuery UI Tabs with no issues. Post code or screenshots of the issue. You can customize the CSS if you want, the default is not going to match your or SPs styles.

Comment: Just added a screenshot.

Comment: A workaround I've found is to remove the css class "ui-helper-clearfix" and add a margin-top to the #tabs .ui-tabs-panel selector.

Comment: yeah i also use jquery ui tabs with no issue. i would take a second look at where the mark up is placed and styles surrounding. you shouldn't need to remove the helper class to get that to work.